# Can someone explain this to me simply?

Tags: javascript, loops, split

I have been trying to wrap my head around this. I came upon this challenge and don't understand what's going on. On top of that, in the for loop there is an X declared - so you can declare two variables in the for loop parentheses?

There was no `var` before the `x` - so that means it's a global variable correct? This is where I'm lost:

```
str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
```

how does this output the whole string with first letter caps - at the end, `str[i].substr(1)` should be the second letter, no? JavaScript is zero-indexed

Challenge here: https://www.w3resource.com/javascript-exercises/javascript-basic-exercise-50.php

```
function capital_letter(str) 
{

    str = str.split(" ");

    for (var i = 0, x = str.length; i < x; i++) {

        str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);
    }

    return str.join(" ");
}

console.log(capital_letter("Write a JavaScript program to capitalize the first letter of each word of a given string."));
```

Comment: `var foo = 1, bar = 2;` is declaring two variables, that works anywhere. `str[i].substr(1)` would be the substring of `str[i]` **starting from** the second letter and continuing to the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Line by line analysis of the code:

str = str.split(" "); // This line splits the given string str on every space character and saves it in array format

For loop expression analysis:

- var i = 0, x = str.length // variable 'i' is initialized to 0 and 'x' to length of string array str i.e. 16
- i < x; i++ // condition determines whether 'i' on each iteration is smaller than 'x' meaning the loop will run 16 times as the 'i' is incremented by 1

Analysing the line - str[i] = str[i][0].toUpperCase() + str[i].substr(1);

- str[i][0].toUpperCase() // Make capital the first letter of each str index
- str[i].substr(1) // take up all letters after only first letter of each str index

At the end the whole word is saved again at the same index

return str.join(" "); // returns the then str array after joining it in to the capitalized sentence

Comment: Thanks for your help.  This line still throws me off.

str[i].substr(1) // take up all letters after only first letter of each str index

(1) is spot 2 in a string - so im just still confused as to how the program knows to print all the words out.  ARGH!!!!!

Comment: Take for example word 'capitalize' as str[5] at that point when the loop is iterating for the 6th time and therefore i = 5, then str[i][0].toUpperCase()  will return 'C' and str[i].substr(1) will return 'apitalize' which in return after concatenation in effect of + operator (the concatenation operator in string context) will become 'Capitalize' and thereafter be saved at str[5].

Comment: actually your confusion is what does substr(1) method call returns and by (1) it doesn't mean spot 2, and means from spot 2 onwards and shouldn't be confused with [1] of array variable call. P.S. notice the brackets for the difference